# How can I add item clicks dynamically on navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, items

I'm having trouble adding items to a navigation drawer dynamically, I've resolved the part of adding the items like this

```
`for(int i = 0; i<lista.size(); i++){
            SubMenu menuGroup = menu.addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, i, Menu.NONE, lista.get(i));
            for(int j = 0; j<5; j++){
                menuGroup.add(item + j);
            }`
```

the problem is here:

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        // Handle the camera action
        //here comes the action for the first item

    } else if (id == R.id.item_2) {
        //here comes the action for item 2 and so on
```

So the thing is that once I've created the items dynamically(already done that), how can I add item clicks (actions for the items already created).
I tried a for loop but because its an  if - else if condition I cannot use a for loop.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same problem before and solved with these way

1. create one fragment with bundle and its layout
2. create method in MainActivity.java
3. call that method in onNavigationItemSelected

after adding FrameLayout in **content_main.xml** with id **frag_layout**, i did these steps:

FragDetail.java

```
public class FragDetail extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_detail, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if(bundle != null) {

        TextView mText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_detail);
        mText.setText(bundle.getString("drawer_title"));
    }

    return view;
}}
```

frag_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="detail clicked"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/txt_detail" /></RelativeLayout>
```

method in MainActivity.java

```
public FragDetail getFragment(String desc) {

    FragDetail frag = new FragDetail();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("drawer_title", desc);

    frag.setArguments(bundle);

    return frag;
}
```

calling method

```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    String nmClient = (String) item.getTitle();

    Fragment frag = getFragment(nmClient);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.frag_layout, frag);
    ft.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

i actually found the solution from this [link](http://dharmangsoni.blogspot.co.id/2014/03/advance-drawer-layout-with-dynamic-fragment-loading.html)

Comment: thanks mate, I finally did it with onNavigationItemSelected, because all the items do the same thing, the only difference is the name, it wasn't as hard as I thought, but your example will come in handy for another project.